# proving a linear transformation is an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T :R2[X]→R2[X]$be linear and such that$T(1)=1+X$,$T(X)=X+X^2$ and
$T (X^2) = 1 − X^2$. Is $T$ an isomorphism?

ok so Ive noticed that $T(1)-T(X)= 1- X^2$ which is $T(X^2)$, but that disproves that its linear, which is already given, also how is this related to it being an isomorphism, am I missing something here or?

Comment: What is $R2[X]$?

Comment: not mentioned :/

Comment: You need to figure out how to write "R2[X]" in tex so there are no ambiguities with your question.

Comment: From context, and my experience, it is likely the vector space of real valued polynomials of degree at most 2.

Comment: yes its a polynomial of degree 2

Comment: Is it written as $\mathbb R2[X]$ ?

Comment: Also, that doesn't disprove linearity, it just shows you that $T(1-x)=T(x^2)$, which means $T$ is not injective (hint).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned yo have
$$T(1)-T(X)=T(X^2)$$

By linearity you get
$$T(1-X)=T(X^2)$$

Therefore $T$ is not one to one.

Comment: oh its in the definition of one to one ! T(u)!= T(v); the only thing i had in mind for 1-1 was that ker is 0

Comment: @ahrnad If you want to use the kernel, use the fact that $T(1-x-x^2)=0$ ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are more comfortable with matrices, and since the problem basically builds one for this transformation for you by applying it to the usual basis of polynomials of degree less than or equal to 2, $1,x,x^2$ the matrix for $T$

$A_T=\begin{bmatrix} T(1)& T(x)& T(x^2) \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&1\\1&1&0\\0&1&-1 \end{bmatrix}$

which you can easily check by expansion by minors has determinant zero, and is not injective, and therefore not bijective (an isomorphism).